Чи варто вживати слово "включати"?
LanguageTool має таке правило:

Правило "Включати і містити"









Опис:
Включати і містити


Повідомлення:
Правильно: містити, (в собі) мати, охоплювати


Категорія:
Варваризми (ID: BARBARISM)


Неправильні повідомлення, які це правило може знайти:
що може в себе включати. Пропозиція виправлення:  містити, (в собі) мати, охоплювати




Горох хоч в розділі Тлумачення для включати і подає:


Уводити в дію.
1.2. Робити активним, дієвим.
Уводити до складу, приєднувати до кого-, чого-небудь.
2.2. Мати у своєму складі; охоплювати.


Aле в розділі Слововживання наводить виправлення, здається, для всіх тлумачень:

включати
Правильніше: додавати; долучати
Мова – не калька: словник української мови
включати телевізор
Правильніше: вмикати телевізор
Мова – не калька: словник української мови
включати світло
Правильніше: вмикати світло
Мова – не калька: словник української мови
включати
Правильніше: містити; охоплювати
Мова – не калька: словник української мови
включати світло
Правильніше: вмикати світло
Словник-антисуржик.
Включати другу швидкість
Правильніше: Вмикати другу швидкість
Довідник з українського слововживання. М. Волощак
дослідження включає…
Правильніше: дослідження містить у собі…
Мова – не калька: словник української мови
Документ включає важні відомості
Правильніше: Документ містить важливі відомості
Довідник з українського слововживання. М. Волощак
Закон включає додатки
Правильніше: Закон має додатки
Довідник з українського слововживання. М. Волощак

А ось з «Як ми говоримо» Антоненка-Давидовича:

Включати, умикати, виключати, вимикати, поставити, унести, пустити
«Треба включити електрику»; «Виключи струм», — кажуть неправильно, забуваючи, що по-українському слід казати: умикнути (увімкнути), умикати електрику, вимикати струм. Від цих дієслів походять і українські технічні терміни: умикач (по-російському включатель) і вимикач (по-російському выключатель). Аналогічно помилково кажуть: «Пропонується включити до порядку денного три питання», — замість «поставити (або внести) до порядку денного». Так само неправильно — «У роботу включили всі існуючі аґреґати», — замість «пустили всі наявні аґреґати».

Взагалі, у мене це питання виникло, коли я натрапив на таку фразу:

зріз масиву a від елемента з індексом 1, включно, до елемента з індексом 4, невключно

і почав шукати як правильніше. Знайшов цікавий варіант перекладу:

Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р. (М. Дорошенко, М. Станиславський, В. Страшкевич)
Включительно – долу́чно; до 21 числа -но – по два́дцять пе́рше число́ долу́чно.


Після прочитаного у мене склалось враження, що треба взагалі виключити вилучити з ужитку слово включати і похідні від нього. Чи це так? Де правда?

Семантично, "містить" це "в межах". Політично визначена територія Росії "включає" географічно відмежований анклав Калінінград, який з часом може бути відчужений або включений до складу інших держав. Це приклад зі невзаємозамінним синонімом. Отже, так, варто вживати, коли на це є потреба.

@RomanMikhol не розумію чому не можна сказати політично визначена територія Росія охоплює (або містить в собі) географічно відмежований анклав? Якщо ви мали на увазі інше речення, то наведіть його, бдл.

Стакан «містить» воду, але не краплю, яка в нього щойно впаде. Вода «містить» мінерали, вони є невідʼємною частиною рідини в стакані. Балтійське море «охоплює» береги Калінінградської області. А територія Рашки «включає» відокремлену територіальну одиницю.

Але ви можете сказати, як вам зручніше. Все одно зрозуміло.

Наразї ҐРАК (версії 17) подаєʼ перші вжитки таким чином:

включити: 1920

Деклярація 2-го грудня 1919 року Варшавської дипльоматичної місії, яка включила фактичну відмову від Галичини, якісь туманні, але прикрі обіцянки про зміну земельного закону і т. д., не найшла ні одного прихильника в наших нарадах.
Соломон Гольдельман. В справі українсько-жидівських відносин.


включати: 1924

Доручити ліквідкомам цих установ включати в свій склад представника од Губфінвідділу , який новинен бути й представником держфондів.
Секретер Неуронов. Офіційний відділ. Радянська Волинь [Житомир] №111


включений: 1931

На Білоруси підіймається фермент, який вповні дав себе відчути потім підчас українсько-московської окупації 1654-5 рр., а в козацькій кругах — серед українського уряду, краще сказавши, наростає переконаннє, що Білорусь повинна перейти, і готова перейти під козацьку протекцію, і при першій можливости мусить бути включена в рамці Козацької Республік , принаймні сумежні білоруські землі.
Михайло Грушевський Історія України-Руси. Том IX



Ітд. Загалом і по сутї початок ⅩⅩ столїття. Це не означаєʼ, що ранїше не було — просто корпус може не мати чи не оціфрував старїші джерела.
До чого це? Вжиток був щонайменше деʼсь під сто років тому і вже усталений, як і занесений в словники. Згаданий вами роздїл слововживання і приклади відти це не про можна чи не можна вживати, а радше про стілістіку, тобто як бажано.
Чомусь ваші джерела наводять лише московську, хоча це радше калька латінських includere (сюди ж інклюзія з подібним сенсом) і побратима excludere, котрих можна зустріти і в гинших мовах як кальку чи повну запозику, напр.: анґл. include і exclude, нїм. einschließen (звідки і відоме нам аншлюз) і ausschließen ітд.
